# Graphs: Prove that this graph is Semi-Eulerian

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path

Prove that a graph is Semi-Eulerian if and only if it has 2 vertices with odd degrees.
Any hints how to start the proof?

Comment: This isn't too hard. How do you think it should start?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** You probably covered the theorem about Eulerian graphs before.

If you did, add an extra edge between the vertices of odd degree, find an Eulerian circuit, make it end at the extra edge and delete.

Answer (score 1):

The graph also needs to be connected. Start by finding a path between the two vertices with odd degree.